# Supress AT code output in the serial monitor on Adafruit Fona

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm, adafruit

I have modified the Adafruit Fona GPS example file to show the error between my location and GPS and GSM locations that it collects. The error part that I'm outputting is showing up correctly, but the AT codes are also displaying on the serial monitor and I can't figure out how to suppress them. Code is below and output is below that. I'm trying to get rid of everything that isn't the line starting with "GPS Error...".

```
/**
 *  ___ ___  _  _   _     ___  __  ___    ___ ___  ___
 * | __/ _ \| \| | /_\   ( _ )/  \( _ )  / __| _ \/ __|
 * | _| (_) | .` |/ _ \  / _ \ () / _ \ | (_ |  _/\__ \
 * |_| \___/|_|\_/_/ \_\ \___/\__/\___/  \___|_|  |___/
 *
 * This example is meant to work with the Adafruit
 * FONA 808 or 3G Shield or Breakout
 *
 * Copyright: 2015 Adafruit
 * Author: Todd Treece
 * Licence: MIT
 *
 */
#include "Adafruit_FONA.h"

// standard pins for the shield, adjust as necessary
#define FONA_RX 2
#define FONA_TX 3
#define FONA_RST 4

const float CURR_LAT = 28.086084;
const float CURR_LON = -82.401916;
float GPS_LAT;
float GPS_LON;
float GSM_LAT;
float GSM_LON;

// We default to using software serial. If you want to use hardware serial
// (because softserial isnt supported) comment out the following three lines 
// and uncomment the HardwareSerial line
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial fonaSS = SoftwareSerial(FONA_TX, FONA_RX);
SoftwareSerial *fonaSerial = &fonaSS;

// Hardware serial is also possible!
//  HardwareSerial *fonaSerial = &Serial1;

Adafruit_FONA fona = Adafruit_FONA(FONA_RST);

// Have a FONA 3G? use this object type instead
//Adafruit_FONA_3G fona = Adafruit_FONA_3G(FONA_RST);


void setup() {

  while (! Serial);

  Serial.begin(115200);
//  Serial.println(F("Adafruit FONA 808 & 3G GPS demo"));
//  Serial.println(F("Initializing FONA... (May take a few seconds)"));

  fonaSerial->begin(4800);
  if (! fona.begin(*fonaSerial)) {
//    Serial.println(F("Couldn't find FONA"));
    while(1);
  }
 // Serial.println(F("FONA is OK"));
  // Try to enable GPRS


 // Serial.println(F("Enabling GPS..."));
  fona.enableGPS(true);
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);

  float latitude, longitude, speed_kph, heading, speed_mph, altitude;

  // if you ask for an altitude reading, getGPS will return false if there isn't a 3D fix
  boolean gps_success = fona.getGPS(&latitude, &longitude, &speed_kph, &heading, &altitude);

  if (gps_success) {

//    Serial.print("GPS lat:");
//    Serial.println(latitude, 6);
//    Serial.print("GPS long:");
//    Serial.println(longitude, 6);
//    Serial.print("GPS speed KPH:");
//    Serial.println(speed_kph);
//    Serial.print("GPS speed MPH:");
//    speed_mph = speed_kph * 0.621371192;
//    Serial.println(speed_mph);
//    Serial.print("GPS heading:");
//    Serial.println(heading);
//    Serial.print("GPS altitude:");
//    Serial.println(altitude);
      GPS_LAT = latitude;
      GPS_LON = longitude;

  } else {
//    Serial.println("Waiting for FONA GPS 3D fix...");
  }

  // Fona 3G doesnt have GPRSlocation :/
  if ((fona.type() == FONA3G_A) || (fona.type() == FONA3G_E))
    return;
  // Check for network, then GPRS 
//  Serial.println(F("Checking for Cell network..."));
  if (fona.getNetworkStatus() == 1) {
    // network & GPRS? Great! Print out the GSM location to compare
    boolean gsmloc_success = fona.getGSMLoc(&latitude, &longitude);

    if (gsmloc_success) {
//      Serial.print("GSMLoc lat:");
//      Serial.println(latitude, 6);
//      Serial.print("GSMLoc long:");
//      Serial.println(longitude, 6);
        GSM_LAT = latitude;
        GSM_LON = longitude;
    } else {
//      Serial.println("GSM location failed...");
//      Serial.println(F("Disabling GPRS"));
      fona.enableGPRS(false);
//      Serial.println(F("Enabling GPRS"));
      if (!fona.enableGPRS(true)) {
//        Serial.println(F("Failed to turn GPRS on"));  
      }
    }
  }

//const float CURR_LAT = 28.086084;
//const float CURR_LON = -82.401916;
//float GPS_LAT;
//float GPS_LON;
//float GSM_LAT;
//float GSM_LON;

float GPS_DIFF = sqrt((GPS_LAT - CURR_LAT)*(GPS_LAT - CURR_LAT) + (GPS_LON - CURR_LON)*(GPS_LON - CURR_LON));
float GSM_DIFF = sqrt((GSM_LAT - CURR_LAT)*(GSM_LAT - CURR_LAT) + (GSM_LON - CURR_LON)*(GSM_LON - CURR_LON));
Serial.print("GPS Error: ");
Serial.print(GPS_DIFF,6);
Serial.print("  GSM Error: ");
Serial.println(GSM_DIFF,6);
}
```

And the output is:

```
GPS Error: 87.056900  GSM Error: 87.056900
    ---> AT+CGNSINF
    <--- +CGNSINF: 1,0,20170529194222.000,,,,0.20,78.0,0,,,,,,12,3,,,25,,
    ---> AT+CREG?
    <--- +CREG: 0,1
    ---> AT+CIPGSMLOC=1,1
    <--- +CIPGSMLOC: 601
    ---> AT+CIPSHUT
    <--- SHUT OK
    ---> AT+SAPBR=0,1
    <--- ERROR
    ---> AT+CIPSHUT
    <--- SHUT OK
    ---> AT+CGATT=1
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","FONAnet"
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CSTT="FONAnet"
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+SAPBR=1,1
    <--- OK
    ---> AT+CIICR
    <--- OK
GPS Error: 87.056900  GSM Error: 87.056900
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Adafruit's library/functions like fona.getGPS and is coded to return information.

It can be edited at the libraries "Adafruit_Fona" folder.